# about managing my network passwords on XP computer

Tags: networking, windows-xp, passwords, user-accounts

I have a question about stored user name and password on XP pro computer.
if you go to control panel - user accounts -pick the account name and there is an option to  click manage my network passwords.
I got this computer from somebody and I checked "system window" under control panel, under my computer name, it says this computer is part of workgroup, not in domain network.
but I checked the manage my network passwords window and I found one saved username something like this.....

```
* server : domainname.com

* user name : www.domainname.com/something
```

this server name, domainname.com address i found on the list seems to exist as an actual website and that stored information seems to be created automatically for some reason(not manually), but I was just wondering what it is exactly.....
**does it mean my computer(my user account) is in a domain network or joining a domain network? or is this just accessing website online?**

here is the link talking about stored username and passwords on XP,
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306541  [stored user name and passwords](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306541)
but I'm still confused because they are talking about domain or domain network? and my computer is in workgroup, not in domain network according to System window panel of my computer.

if anyone can help me with some answer, I would really appreciate it!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you have answered your own question. Your computer is not a member of a domain and that saved password is saved for a website. What exactly is your question please?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. i just wanted to make sure that my computer is not a member of a domain because only way I know how to check it is going to system window panel. And it says it's in workgroup, but I saw that little odd stored username which does not look like a normal username to log into websites(I thought). so I was a little concerned that if my computer really is not in any domain network because I don't have much knowledge about computer:)

Comment: A computer doesn't need to be *part of* a domain just to access resources in one. Even standalone (workgroup) systems can log on to domain systems. (Although I must note that "www.domainname.com/something" is a very unusual username to have stored.)

Answer (score 0):

The output of either `net config workstation` or `systeminfo` should help.